# React context provider - cant pass dispatch as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to use react hooks and context to implement the `useReducer` hook.  Everything works fine except the dispatch function is not defined in the child component:

```
let initialState = {
  isLoading: false
};
let reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "show_loader":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    default:
      return;
  }
};
const AppContext = createContext(initialState);

function AppProvider({ children }) {
  const { Provider } = AppContext;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return <Provider value={value}>{children}</Provider>;
}
export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

And then in my child component I have the following:

```
function NewFont(props){
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppContext);
    console.log(state, dispatch)
    ....
}
```

The log gives me `{isLoading: false}` for state but the dispatch function comes back as `undefined`.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: You need to show more of the code involved. This works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8471q9y9nj

Comment: I suspect you aren't putting `NewFont` as a child of `AppProvider`, so it is just receiving the `initialState` which doesn't include the `dispatch` function.